# Black area when exporting graph from svg (d3.js) to jpg

Tags: svg, d3.js, todataurl

I am trying to export a graph from SVG (obtained through d3.js) to a JPG image using javascript.

The fact is that the final image do not show the picture properly but it draws a black area enclosing the lines of the graph. [Here](http://postimg.org/image/3ztlt0ti7/) they are the two images. At the top of the page the SVG is represented whereas the final JPG image is depicted.

The code I have written is the following:

```
    root_node = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("version", 1.1)
      .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
      .node();

    s_xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(root_node);

    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml,'+ s_xml;
    var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">';

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.width = 1600;
    canvas.height = 600;

    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;
    image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        context.fillStyle = 'white';
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        var jpgimg = '<img src="'+canvasdata+'">';
        d3.select("body").append("svgdataurl").html(jpgimg);

    });
```

Anyone knows the reason of the wrong colours transformation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the source of the SVG to the question?

Comment: I would guess that in your CSS you have declared the fill of paths to be none. This isn't picked up when you convert, you have to set styles etc in the D3 code.

Comment: The source of the SVG can be consulted [here](http://pastebin.com/XELkdyqY).

Answer (score 6):

You have to directly give the CSS for the line chart in the D3 code.

```
lineChart.append("path")
.attr("class", "lineChart")
.attr("stroke-width", 1)
.attr("fill","none")
.attr("d", valueline(lineChartData));
```